# Nominatim european map indexing/import

Tags: postgresql, nominatim

I have installed nominatim on my local centOS 6.6 machine following the wiki.guide there http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation
I follow the instructions line to line and I manage to import a little map (monaco-latest.osm.pbf) and everything goes fine. Now I tried to import the european map (15.8 gb), i follow the same procedure, I launch the command

```
 ./utils/setup.php --osm-file european.latest.osm.pbf --all --osm2pgsql-cache 2048 2>&1 | tee setup.log
```

5 days ago and if I launch the command *ps -aux | more* I see the following output for nominatim/postgres process:

```
500      25306  0.0  0.0 230024   528 ?        S    Oct14   0:00 /usr/bin/php -C
q ./utils/setup.php --osm-file /srv/mappe/europe-latest.osm.pbf --all --osm2pgsq l-cache 2048
postgres 25310  0.0  0.0 509284  2792 ?        Ss   Oct14   0:00 postgres: mapserver nominatim [local] idle
500      25336  2.6 51.3 3908808 2015768 ?     R    Oct14 182:24 /srv/Nominatim-2.3.1/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore -C 2048 -P 5432 -d nominatim /srv/mappe/europe-latest.osm.pbf
postgres 25338  0.7  3.6 352208 142580 ?       Ss   Oct14  49:17 postgres: mapserver nominatim [local] COPY
postgres 25339 39.3  3.5 325964 141056 ?       Rs   Oct14 2726:28 postgres: mapserver nominatim [local] idle in transaction
postgres 25340  0.2  3.5 326520 141116 ?       Ss   Oct14  16:17 postgres: mapserver nominatim [local] COPY
postgres 25341  0.0  0.0 325808  3156 ?        Ss   Oct14   0:00 postgres: mapserver nominatim [local] COPY
```

If, I launch the command:

```
psql -d postgres -c "select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'nominatim'"
```

I see some log but, a thing that worry me a lot, if I write the follow code:

```
su - postgres
\connect nominatim
\dt
```

I see just 9 table...

What I have to do?? The process is still running?? Is stucked??

I'm trying to install the european map in a machine with centOS 6.7 and 250gb Disk space 4gb ram

Please help me.
Thanks a lot

Hi Artur and thanks a lot for your response.
Now, reading your post I'm pretty sure that the process is busy because the setup.log is the same since 4 days..
An important question: can I set the osm2pgsql -cache up to 18000 even if my machine RAM is 4GB?? I have read that the cache should be half of machine RAM, than if I have 4gb RAM cache should be 2048. Is it correct??
Than now I tried to install the map in another machine, with 500 gb HD and 16gb RAM (is a centos 6.6 virtual machine).
When I launch the map import I redirect the standard output and error to two different file:
In the setup.log I can see some create table and some insert (file is about 100 row) and at the bottom of the file I see IMPORT
Than I read the error.log file and I see an output like this:

```
NOTICE:  table "place" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "keyvalue" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "wordscore" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "stringlanguagetype" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  type "keyvaluetype" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  function get_connected_ways(pg_catalog.int4[]) does not exist, skipping
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse Node-cache: cache=2048MB, maxblocks=262144*8192, allocation method=11 Mid: pgsql, scale=10000000 cache=2048
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_nodes" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_ways" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_rels" does not exist, skipping
Reading in file: /srv/mappe/europe-latest.osm.pbf
Processing: Node(10k 10.0k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)
Processing: Node(20k 20.0k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)
...
```

And so on.. is the third time that I try to install this damned map and is the third time that the process stop at:

```
Processing: Node(1561860k 141.1k/s) Way(6002k 0.04k/s) Relation(0 0.00/s)
```

Exactly at this point the process stopped, and two times I see an error similar to 'gazzetter error exectuing external command' and another time no error appear and the process just stopped.
Why this scenario?? Why the process stopped exactly at that point?
Please help I googling a lot but I don't find nothing.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should check **setup.log** if its growing with content similar to:

```
  Done 930027 in 17491 @ 53.171745 per second - Rank 30 ETA (seconds): 1053255.375000
```

It means, that import task processed 930027 elements in 17491 seconds which gives about 53.171745 objects per second, so estimated time is 1053255 seconds.

You have 30 ranks, as far as I remember 26th and 30th are the biggest ones.

If you want to speed it up maybe try working with PG performance settings as its written in [Nominatim installation guide PG Tuning section](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#PostgreSQL_Tuning).

I see that cache you gave to *osm2pgsql* process is pretty low. Try maybe with `18000`.

You can also work on parallelizing this operation by adding `--threads n` option. Where *n* is threads amount. Default is *number of CPUs - 1*.

If everythink works OK but is slow maybe you have bottleneck somewhere (disk IO operations, insufficient memory or maybe just CPU is to slow).

My last import of Europe took about 10 days on i7/32GB RAM/7200 HDD so dont expect it to work immediately.

Comment: I know that you do not have enough rep, but when you have this answer belongs in comments... For now we are happy that you try to help. To convert into an answer indicate how SO can undertand viewing the setup.log if he is stuck